# Running `bash` using docker exec with xargs command

Tags: docker, xargs

I've been trying to execute bash on running docker container which has specific name as follows. **`--(1)`**

```
docker ps | grep somename | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs -I'{}' docker exec -it '{}'
```

but it didn't work and it shows a message like

> "docker exec" requires at least 2 argument(s)

when I tried using command as follows **`--(2)`**

```
docker ps | grep somename | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs docker exec -it
```

it shows another error messages like

> the input device is not a TTY

But when I tried using $() (sub shell) then it can be accomplished but I  cannot understand why it does not work with the two codes **(1)(2)** above (using xargs)

Could any body explain why those happen?

I really appreciate any help you can provide in advance =)

**EDIT 1:**

I know how to accomplish my goal in other way like

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep perf | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' )
```

But I'm just curious about why those codes are not working =)

Comment: Your EDIT 1 was the only solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- First question

> "docker exec" requires at least 2 argument(s)

In last pipe command, standard input of **xargs** is, for example, `42a9903486f2 bash`. And you used **xargs** with **-I** (replace string) option.
So, docker recognizes that `42a9903486f2 bash` is a first argument, without 2nd argument.

Below example perhaps is the what you expected.

```
docker ps | grep somename | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs bash -c 'docker exec -it $0 $1'
```

- Second question

> the input device is not a TTY

**xargs** excutes command on new child process. So you need to reopen stdin to child process for interactive communication. (MacOS: -o option)

```
docker ps | grep somename | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs -o docker exec -it
```

Comment: This is perfect answer that I expected. I really appreciate your kind answer =) It really helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo docker ps -q | xargs -I'{}' docker exec -t {} du -hs /tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

The exec command you run is something like this:

```
docker exec -it 'a1b2c3d4 bash'
```

And that is only one argument, not two. You need to remove the quotes around the argument to docker exec.

```
... | xargs -I'{}' docker exec -it {}
```

Then you will exec properly with two arguments.

```
docker exec -it a1b2c3d4 bash
                 ------   ---
         first arg ^       ^ second arg
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.

I also tried using

    "docker ps | grep somename | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' | xargs -I'{}' docker exec -it {}"

but It didn't work for me ^^; 

It show the message `"docker exec" requires at least 2 argument(s)` like the result of first try.

Comment: @user3400490 What error do you get in that attempt?

Comment: `"docker exec" requires at least 2 argument(s) like the result of first try. ` as the edited comment above =)

Comment: @Abraxas5 Above you have `docker exec -it` without the `{}` following. Two different things... did you try with `{}` but with no quotes around it?

Comment: on a sidenote, you shoudl use `docker ps --filter` see this (outdated) doc https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/ps/ and the examples

Comment: @DanLowe My answer is YES. and there is following **`{}`** after that `docker exec -it` (maybe you didn't see because of the line change)

@user2915097 Thanks, but sorry. I don't understand what you intended. I know the filter and format option with docker ps. But I want to do partial match of Image name and even if I use that ps filter what I really wanted to do is execute **`docker exec`** command with filtered id using xargs. I can accomplish my goal with `docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep perf | awk '{print  $1 " bash"}' )` but I want to know why the codes above are not working.

Comment: the name of a container is unique, maybe you could start it with a specific name, find it with the filter, as it would be more reliable

Comment: @user2915097 I can understand what you mean, but I think you didn't get my point ^^; But I really appreciate for your concern =)